# Web page won't fully load in blackberry device

Tags: android, asp.net, blackberry

I have an asp.net application. When I try to load some of the web pages on different devices, it gives me different results.

In blackberry q10, it only loads content that fits to the screen size. I can't scroll down and the page doesn't move.

It works perfectly with iphone 5s and chrome browser.

Can anyone please tell me how to have similar responsive UI designs for all the devices?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post some source HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
It was <form> tag. I removed it and the page loaded perfectly.
```